# Typo on on-topic page in help center

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

The [on-topic](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page in the help center begins with:

> Lifehacks is a place to ask about seemingly intractable, stubborn problems that need a bit of thinking "outside the box". *If our question is*

Could that be changed to 'If your question is', because right now it doesn't match with what comes a little bit later:

> …then you are in the right place.